# Query custom table in form builder auto responder

Tags: c#, forms, macros, kentico

I have a custom form built using Kentico form builder. In my form, I reference a custom table via a foreign key...meaning that my form stores the id that is a reference to my custom table data. In my auto responder is there any way to retrieve the actual value from my custom table using the id value from my form?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by [creating a custom macro](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Registering+custom+macro+methods) that accepts the FK value as an argument, looks up the corresponding record in your custom table, and returns the field on that record that you need as a string.  Then you just have to use the macro in the autoresponder editor - same as you would anywhere else - and pass in the $$label:FieldName$$ as the argument.

The hardest part of this will be using Kentico's API to get the data from the custom table.  [Here are some examples for managing custom table data using their API](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0rc/devguide/index.html?custom_tables_api_examples_managing_custom_table_data.htm).  It's not really that hard, just a takes a little more code than it should.

Personally, I prefer creating Entity or LINQtoSQL classes for my custom tables and using those instead, especially if it's a table I'm going to be working with a lot.  The only thing you're really losing is a couple of built-in calls to other CMS functions like updating smart search indexes and I think logging things to the staging module, both of which you can just add in later if you needed to.

Comment: Instead of using Entity or LINQ you might look at the code automatically generated by Kentico on the Code tab of the custom table.  Not only are you losing the CMS functions but you're also losing the built-in caching.  IMHO using the API is a better approach because you get to have all the other benefits that come with it.  Good answer though with the custom macro method.

Comment: @BrendenKehren I agree, stick with the API. Good answer by Jerreck re: Custom Macro, I have provided some code to demonstrate that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Jerreck is correct you can do this with a Custom Macro.

If you are going to make a Custom Macro, I suggest you make the Custom Macro as re-usable as possible by passing it a few additional parameters. For example;

```
customTableItemID = 231;    
customTableCodeName = "customtable.TableName";    
customTableReturnColumnName = "DisplayName";
```

At least that way you can re-use the same Custom Macro for other Custom Tables and return different fields from the table.

Assuming you are using Kentico v8, the following code works for me;

**CustomMacroMethods.cs**

```
using System;
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.MacroEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.CustomTables;

//declare CustomMacroNamespace
[Extension(typeof(CustomMacroMethods))]
public class CustomMacroNamespace : MacroNamespace<CustomMacroNamespace>
{
}

//register CustomMacroNamespace into the macro engine
[MacroNamespaceLoader]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Attribute class that ensures the registration of custom macro namespaces.
   /// </summary>
   private class MacroNamespaceLoaderAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Called automatically when the application starts.
      /// </summary>
      public override void Init()
      {
         // Registers "CustomNamespace" into the macro engine
          MacroContext.GlobalResolver.SetNamedSourceData("CustomMacroNamespace", CustomMacroNamespace.Instance);
      }
   }
}

//declare custom macro methods
public class CustomMacroMethods : MacroMethodContainer
{

   [MacroMethod(typeof(object), "Returns the Value of a Column in a Custom Table as an object.", 3)]
   [MacroMethodParam(0, "CustomTableCodeName", typeof(string), "The Custom Table code name. Eg customtable.TableName")]
   [MacroMethodParam(1, "CustomTableItemID", typeof(int), "The ID of the to return.")]    
   [MacroMethodParam(2, "CustomTableReturnColumnName", typeof(string), "The field name of the column containing the value to return")]
   public static object GetCustomTableValue(EvaluationContext context, params object[] parameters)
  {
    if (parameters.Length == 3)
    {

        string customTableCodeName = ValidationHelper.GetString(parameters[0], "");
        int customTableID = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(parameters[1], -1);
        string customTableReturnFieldName = ValidationHelper.GetString(parameters[2], "");

        CustomTableItem cti = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItem(customTableID, customTableCodeName);
        if (cti != null)
        {
            return cti.GetValue(customTableReturnFieldName);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Custom macro GetCustomTableValue() requires three parameters");
    }

  }

}
```

**Usage**

```
{% CustomMacroNamespace.GetCustomTableValue("customtable.TableName", 1, "DisplayName")  #%}
```

Refer to the documentation for further information.
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Registering+custom+macro+methods
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+macro+namespaces